# Regex needed to match a domain name for django view

Tags: regex, django, django-urls, alphanumeric

I'm trying to match a url with a domain like:

Testing.com
testing.com
Testing.net
testing.net
Testing.org
testing.org

and other extensions as well.

I'm trying to formulate a regex to use in a django view like:

```
(r'^Account/Testing/d=([a-z]{1,50})$', TestApp),
```

I tried `^[A-za-z]{2,50}$` but that doesn't match a domain with capital letter in the beginning

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you want to do something like `([a-z]*\.[a-z]{2,})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this wasn't that bad after all - this is one way to match a domain with varying extensions:

```
^[A-za-z]{2,50}.[a-z]{1,3}$
```

matches .com, .org, .net, etc.

If you have a domain like me2.com, its better to use this:

```
(^[A-za-z0-9]{2,50}.[a-z]{1,3})$
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3})\.([a-z_0-9-]+\.\w{2,3}(?:\.\w{2})?)/i
```

it will match for links likes this

http://www.site.com
https://www.site.com
http://www.site.co.uk
https://www.site.co.uk
http://www.site.com.br
https://www.site.com.br
http://www.site-site.com.br
https://www.site-site.com
http://www.site-site.co.uk
https://www.site-site.co.uk
www.site-site.com
www.site-site.co.uk
www.site-site.com.br
www.site.com

and alot of other variations

even if the site has
www.site.com/news

it will only match for "site.com"

the /i modifier will match for all variations of upper and lower cases

if you only want to match domain name as upper and lower

```
/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:w{3})\.((?i:[a-z_0-9-])+\.\w{2,3}(?:\.\w{2})?)/
```

(?i:[a-z_0-9-]) will match variations for domain's names only